# CSS não carrega no HTML

Tags: java, html, css

Galera, quando ocorre uma exceção no doFilter(Filter) é executado o código abaixo:

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("maintenance.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

O direcionamento para a página ocorre, porém o css referenciado no HTML não ocorre.

Abaixo está o código no HTML da referência ao css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/maintenance.css">
```

Já tentei com mas não deu certo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/css/maintenance.css">
```

O HTML está na pasta WebContent, já o css esté em WebContent/resource/css

Tem algo errado?

Comment: já entou colocar o type="text/css" ? se não estiver trabalhando com html5 é necessário

Comment: Sim, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Há uma diferença entre `WebContent/resource/css` e `WebContent/resources/css`... o `resource` do primeiro está no singular e o segundo no plural.

Comment: Corrigindo, O HTML está na pasta WebContent, já o css esté em WebContent/resources/css, erro de digitação.

Comment: A sua pasta css foi adicionada no path do projeto? Veja no browser com F12 se o .css está sendo carregado. Acredito que seja um problema de caminhos